# Using compound conditions in a Bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, comparison

I want to do something like below in Bash script. How do I implement it in Bash syntax?

```
if !((a==b) && (a==c))
then
    # Do something
end if
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For numeric comparison, you can do:

```
if ! (( (a == b) && (a == c) ))
```

For string comparison:

```
if ! [[ "$a" == "$b" && "$a" == "$c" ]]
```

In Bash, the double parentheses set up an arithmetic context (in which dollar signs are mostly optional, by the way) for a comparison (also used in `for ((i=0; i<=10; i++))` and `$(())` arithmetic expansion) and is used to distinguish the sequence from a set of single parentheses which creates a subshell.

This, for example, executes the command `true` and, since it's always true it does the action:

```
if (true); then echo hi; fi
```

This is the same as

```
if true; then echo hi; fi
```

except that a subshell is created. However, `if ((true))` tests the value of a variable named "true".

If you were to include a dollar sign, then "$true" would unambiguously be a variable, but the `if` behavior with single parentheses (or without parentheses) would change.

```
if ($true)
```

or

```
if $true
```

would execute the contents of the variable as a command and execute the conditional action based on the command's exit value (or give a "command not found" message if the contents aren't a valid command).

```
if (($true))
```

does the same thing as `if ((true))` as described above.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. This is exactly the type of syntax I was looking for

Comment: +1 for the explanation of double parantheses! Deleting my other comments for clean up.

Answer (score 6):

```
if [ "$a" != "$b" -o "$a" != "$c" ]; then
  # ...
else
  # ...
fi
```

Comment: Or, doing the direct translation: `if [ ! \\( \\( "$a" = "$b" \\) -a \\( "$a" = "$c" \\) \\) ]`...

Comment: The logic for reversing the operators like this is [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

a=2
b=3
c=4

if ! (( (a == b) && (a == c) )); then
  # stuff here
fi
```

You could also use the following which I personally find more clear:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=2
b=3
c=4

if (( (a != b) || (a != c) )); then
  # stuff here
fi
```

Technically speaking, you don't need the parentheses around the sub expressions since the equality operators `== !=` have higher precedence than both the compound comparison operators `&& ||`, but I think it's wise to keep them in there to show the intent, if nothing else.

Comment: Thanks SiegeX great explanation here!